# Display all SQL executed in Eloquent in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i have this route in my `web.php`:

```
Route::get('task' , function(){
   return App\Carsoul::all();
});
```

this code return:

```
[{"id":12,"image":"1502286679.jpg"},{"id":14,"image":"1502287112.jpg"}]
```

i want to display query that return above result so i add this code before `Route`:

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query){
  var_dump($query);
});
```

expect to return like:`SELECT* FROM 'carsouls' ...`
but return same result:

```
[{"id":12,"image":"1502286679.jpg"},{"id":14,"image":"1502287112.jpg"}]
```

what is the mistake?

Comment: You should probably look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging. It's for version 5.0, which is a little outdated, but unless they removed it, it should still be available to you. Or from the 5.4 documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#listening-for-query-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you want to show the query as a string in Eloquant you can try

`Model::orderBy('id','ASC')->toSql()` it returns complete query.

Hope this helps

Comment: return : 'Method toSql does not exist'

Comment: @mohsen.MY you are trying  it with `all()` which returns collections. you should give it a try with `Model::orderBy('id','ASC')->toSql()`.